# Tensorflow 2.0 Conv3D input_shape Problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I' trying to train a CNN on video sequences. My input_data has the shape (5874, 1, 10, 128, 128) which represent (n_samples, channels, frames, height , width). The error is either 4 dimensions are given but 5 expected or 6 dimensions were given. What is the correct way to manage Conv3D?

setting `Input((1,10,128,128))` results to: `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 128, 128, 10)`. but the error is generated after fitting.

setting `Input((1,1,10,128,128))` results to:`ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv3d_6 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=5, found ndim=6. Full shape received: [None, 1, 1, 128, 128, 10]` after executing the model (before fitting)

I already went through all possible documentation and forums and found nothing. Any tips would be helpful.

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data, labels)))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(10000)
train_dataset, valid_dataset = split_dataset(dataset, 0.02)


model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(Input((1,10,128,128)))
model.add(Conv3D(filters = 8, kernel_size=(10,5,5), padding="same", activation="relu", data_format="channels_first"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv3D(filters = 8, kernel_size=(10,3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPool3D(pool_size=(1,2,2), strides=(1,1,1)))

model.add(Conv3D(filters = 16, kernel_size=(5,5,5), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv3D(filters = 16, kernel_size=(5,3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPool3D(pool_size=(2,2,2), strides=(1,1,1)))

model.add(Conv3D(filters = 32, kernel_size=(5,5,5), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv3D(filters = 32, kernel_size=(3,3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPool3D(pool_size=(2,2,2), strides=(1,1,1)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(512, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(5, activation="softmax"))



model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01)  , loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
r = model.fit(train_dataset, verbose=1, validation_data=valid_dataset, epochs=50)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the model Tensorflow adds a dimension at the beginning of the data for iteration. So the Input should get only the last four dimensions. But the `fit` needs 5. after using `Dataset.from_tensor_slices`, `dataset.batch` must be used otherwise there is an error while fitting.